# Cambiar la el punto decimal del double por una coma

Tags: java, bucle-for, bucles

Resulta que el ouput sale punto de los doubles y lo que quiero es cambiarlo por una coma

[image]

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, evita usar imágenes para compartir código o mensajes de error. Todo eso lo puedes copiar y pegar como texto en tu pregunta y así harás más fácil que otros LEAN y repliquen tu problema

Comment: la respuesta va como una respuesta, abajo. Acá ni siquiera le puedes dar formato.

Comment: ya me di cuenta pero gracias de todo modos

Comment: Entonces pon tu respuesta abajo y con eso los demás te la votamos positiva (y de paso, los demás se enteran cuál es la solución, ahora y en el futuro). Y no, aquí no se pone solucionado a la pregunta.

Comment: vale ahora lo hago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres lograr tu objetivo puedes usar el metodo replaceAll("\.", ",").

A continuación te muestro como  puedes usarlo en el método listarElementos.:

```
public void listarElementos() {
        for (int i = 0; i < codigo.length; i++) {
            if (codigo[i] != null) {
                System.out.println("El codigo es : " + codigo[i] + ", el nombre del producto es : "
                        + nombre[i] + " , el precio de compra es de : "
                        + precioCompra[i].toString().replaceAll("\\.", ",")
                        + " , el precio " + "de venta es de : " + precioVenta[i].toString().replaceAll("\\.", ",") + " y el stock es de"
                        + " : " + stock[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: la voy a mirrar gracias

Comment: `El codigo es : 1, el nombre del producto es : queso , el precio de compra es de : 32,5 , el precio de venta es de : 35,6 y el stock es de : 20`  tu respuesta me fue util muchas gracias

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar dos cosas para cambiar la coma la primera seria indicarle los separadores

```
DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.'); 
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(formatString, otherSymbols);
```

Y la otra opción es indicarle un lenguaje que tenga la coma como decimal esta en toda europa con lo que cualquier pais europeo te sirve

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
```

Comment: gracias voi a mirrar ambas